# Does the following inequality hold $x^p y^q \le \left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^{\frac{p+q}{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, inequality

Let $x,y>0$, and $p,q$ be positive integers. Is the following inequality true?
\begin{align}
x^p y^q \le \left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^{\frac{p+q}{2}}.
\end{align}

---

The term $\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^{1/2}$ can be treated as the average of $x$ and $y$. Intuitively, the above inequality is true. Can we prove it? Otherwise, is there any counter example?

Comment: $373248 = 2^93^6 > 13^5 = 371293$. So, $2^43^6 > \left( \dfrac{2^2 + 3^2}{2} \right)^{\frac{4 + 6}{2}}$.

Comment: If on the right hand side you also had a weighted average, with the same weights as in the weighted geometric mean on the left, then yes. It would be just the inequality between weighted arithmetic and geometric means.

Comment: Have a look at [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products).

Comment: It *is* true for $p=q=1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not true.

Take any $x\in(0,1)$, $y=1$ and fix $p$ any positive integer. Then the lhs is $x^p$, which is positive and does not depend on $q$. Yet the rhs is the number $(x^2+1)/2\in(0,1)$ to the power $(p+q)/2$, which vanishes as $q$ goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is a nice example.

Comment: In my counterexample I let $q$ go to $+\infty$, which implies that it is a counterexample for $q$ large enough. By the way, the inequality is always true for $p=q$, even for integers different from $1$.